# Make custom opener for file manager

Tags: file, sh, default

I am currently using the file manager [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn). I want to be able to open all currently selected files. *This question is not specific to nnn*
hence I wrote an opener

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

sel=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/nnn/.selection

if [ -s $sel ]; then
    while IFS= read -r file; do
        echo "$file"
        xdg-open $file > /dev/null
    done < $sel
    xdg-open $1
else
    xdg-open $1
fi
```

basic rundown
$1: currently hovered file
$sel: the file containing the currently selected files with each file in a line.
like 
<file 1>\n
<file 2>\n
<file 3>\n

But when run this script it only opens the currently hovered file.

Comment: Because you are not quoting the variable properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)